# How to move an SKNode?

Tags: swift, user-interface, sprite-kit, pan

I'm writing a Pong-like game using SpriteKit and Swift 5 for learning purpose. And I'm trying to made the player's paddle (an SKNode rectangle) move across the screen in the x coordinate but couldn't.

I've tried this simple solution:

```js
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        let location = t.location(in: self)

        playerPaddle.position.x = location.x
    }
```

It works but seems like the paddle only moves on clicks (touches), but not drags.

Also I've tried using the UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I don't really understand how to call it, here is the code which I copied from the official Apple Developer's doc and changed a little to match my situation:

```js
@IBAction func panPiece(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else {return}
    let piece = gestureRecognizer.view!
    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: piece.superview)
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        self.initialPos = piece.center
    }
    else if gestureRecognizer.state != .changed {
        let newPos = CGPoint(x: initialPos.x + translation.x, y: initialPos.y)
        piece.center = newPos
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to guess that playerPaddle is an empty SKNode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `touchesMoved` solution works for me, so I'd assume that something else is amiss. Regardless, I can offer an alternative:

I also built Pong to learn Swift and SpriteKit, and I implemented the paddle movement using SKActions. Any time a touch begins, cancel the paddle's current actions and begin moving to the new x location.

If you want to keep it simple to start, then you can have a constant move time, like 0.5 seconds. Otherwise, you can calculate the time to move by getting the absolute distance between the paddle and touch location and dividing by some constant. Changing the constant will change the speed at which the paddle moves.

Here's an example with the constant move time:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if playerPaddle.hasActions() { playerPaddle.removeAllActions() }

    for touch in touches {
        let newX = touch.location(in: self).x
        let oldX = playerPaddle.position.x
        playerPaddle.run(.moveBy(x: newX - oldX, y: 0, duration: 0.5))
    }
}
```